# How to replace the list of items with new list in room persistence?

Tags: android, persistence, dao, android-room

the Entity consists of only one item id ,which is the primaryKey as well, I'm storing in DB for example 3 items, when the list is updated, with new 3 items I need to replace the existing list with new one. but in my case it adds new ones ,but I need totally replace existing ones

```
  @Dao
public interface UserIdDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM userIds")
Flowable<List<UserId>> allUserIds();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 List<Long> update(List<UserId> ids);
}

@Entity
public class UserId{
  @PrimaryKey
  private Long id;

 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) return true;
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

UserId userId = (UserFavoriteStore) o;

return (!id.equals(userId.id));
 }
@Override


public int hashCode() {
int result = id.hashCode();
result = 31 * result + (id.hashCode());
return result;
 }}
```

Comment: "when the list is updated" -- what list?

Comment: List<Long> update(List<UserId> ids);
I mean List of UserId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to replace the existing list with new one. but in my case it adds new ones ,but I need totally replace existing ones

You wrote code to retrieve IDs and insert IDs. You have no code to delete IDs.

So, add a `@Delete` method to your DAO to delete IDs that you no longer need. Then, when you want to replace the IDs, delete the ones you no longer need with your `@Delete` method and `@Insert` the ones that you want to have instead.

`OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` says "if you try to insert a row that matches an existing row by their primary keys, do not crash, but instead <strike>replace the other columns in that existing row</strike> delete the offending rows before inserting the new ones" (see [the SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)). In your case:

- You have no other columns
- Inserting new IDs will not match existing IDs by their primary keys, since your data is completely a primary key

Comment: Ok ,if I add the column name(String) which could be unique ,but it's not primaryKey as it is String ,could it be done without deleting  ,only with insert method?

Comment: @A.A.I.A: First, a primary key can be a string. Second, I do not think that Room supports `UNIQUE` constraints at this time, only unique indices, and I do not know off the top of my head how SQLite's `REPLACE` strategy handles that scenario.

Comment: one more question If I have 2 fragment in first one I call allUserIds() and in second I only call update/delete, if I go back to the first fragment it should be updated because the return type is flowable and I have rx. subscriptions , yes?

Comment: @A.A.I.A: Probably, though I am sure that there are plenty of ways in which that can go wrong.

Comment: even I added fetching with subscription in the same fragment in onAttach() but after DB update it doesn't call the subscription of fetching the DB ,why?